# Working in jupyter, trying to plot time series

Tags: jupyter

I just want to use any simple seaborn or matplot plot to visualize my data set as a lineplot. Please help. I cant seem to figure out how to plot these values i keep getting all types of errors.
My data set consists of 4 columns, the first is date which I want to plot on my x axis and the rest are numeric values of gold, oil and the dollar that I want to plot.

I have my dates set to datetime value and the rest set to float64, I am trying to plot the fluctuations of oil, gold and the dollar over time to look at any possible correlation. Sorry for any obvious mistakes I am not an expert.

Doing This gives me only one plotted value and the Date values on x axis is incorrect

```
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Values')

plt.title('Historical Data')

df['Price_Gold'].plot()
```

So basically im running into trouble when trying to plot multiple values against time.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html